# Total Datastage Jobs Greater Than My Max Jobs I Set

Tags: ibm-information-server

I have below system policies defined in InfoSphere DataStage Operations Console under "Work Load Management(WLM)".

Sometimes, the total number of currently running jobs shoots upto 150 although I have defined maximum running job count as 40 in WLM.

Whenever the currently running job count increases beyond 100, most of the datastage jobs starts showing increased startup time in director log and they took long time to run otherwise if the job concurrency is less than 100 then the same set of jobs run fine with startup time in seconds. Please suggest how to address this issue and how to enforce currently running job should not exceed eg 100 at any point of time. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

This is working as designed, generally the WLM system is used to control the start of parallel and server jobs. It uses a set of user-defined queues and when a job is started, it is submitted to a designated queue. In the figure above the parallel jobs are in queue named 'MediumPriorityJobs'.

Note that the sequence job is not in the queue to be counted to the total running workloads controlled by the WLM Job Count System Policy.

Source: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-interpret-job-count-maximum-running-jobs-system-policy-ibm-infosphere-information-server-workload-management-wlm